# Why do some of my TDS levels not display properly?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I'm playing Tiny Death Star on iPad, however several of my apartment levels and even some business look the same, even though I know they shouldn't. They are all on levels over 50.

I have noticed as well that if I go to Menu and choose "Levels", the pics of the affected levels are blank. The other ones display properly. In addition, I have only had two of the three Imperial Assignments showing up for the past two days. Before that there were three going 'round the clock.

Is there a way to correct this? I'm afraid if I delete this and reload it I  will lose all my progress.

Comment: Is this iOS?   Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Have you tried completely closing the app (force closing, if needed), and going back into it to see if that fixes it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Tiny Death Star has been [discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star), as such if you are unable to workaround the bug/issue by restarting the application or your device, then there's nothing we can do: there is **no fix coming** from the developers:

> The game was removed from the Apple App Store and Google Play Store by Disney in October 2014.

As you are playing on iOS, I would not recommend uninstalling the game if you wish to keep it. Only those who had [previously downloaded the game on Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star#Bugs) can still redownload & access the game.

Comment: Note: this answer is a [community-proposed solution](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13064/28182) for unresolved Tiny Death Star bug questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing in a WP, you will have some levels that don't have a background, there is no way to correct them but the levels work well (with the exception of holofilm rental that closes the App if you try to order something). The levels are shuttle bay, life support, Twilek apts & holofilm rental. I guess we'll have to wait for an update.